# Can I ask something related to flexitarianism on vegetarianism?

Tags: discussion, tags

If I had 150 rep and a question about flexitarianism, would vegetarianism.se.com a relevant place to post it?

If you do not know what this diet is, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-vegetarianism) can help:

> A semi-vegetarian or flexitarian diet is one that is plant-based with the occasional inclusion of meat. In 2003, the American Dialect Society voted flexitarian as the year's most useful word.

A somewhat popular kind of flexitarian diet are the weekday vegetarianism:

*(The image below is a link to a TED talk video.)*
[image]

> We all know the arguments that being vegetarian is better for the environment and for the animals -- but in a carnivorous culture, it can be hard to make the change. Graham Hill has a powerful, pragmatic suggestion: Be a weekday veg.

If they were created, semi-vegetarianism and flexitarianism tags should be synonym.

Comment: @Zanna djechlin's answer somewhat answer my question. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: P.S. reputation of the asker should never bear on whether a question is on topic... though it might have an unwarranted influence on the community perception thereof

Comment: @Zanna I am familiar with stack exchange. Thank you though. It may have been useful :)